# using neo4j get spanning tree from graph with loops

Tags: neo4j

I want to find the spanning tree from graph with loops. I cannot use regular bfs traversal here. so I check the allsimplepaths java function api, It seems find loop between two nodes. right now i select a random root, but don't know the end points. so i just want to get the spanning tree from graph while the it has many loops maybe. so it should convert to DAG and then give the tree structures. The graph may have more than one spanning tree. 
how to do this? can allsimplepaths applied here?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [TraversalDescription](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) with an appropriate uniqueness (NODE_GLOBAL) and Path-Expanders that follow the interesting relationships.

Comment: hi, i test the neo4j java api to do traversal description, when i start from one node, i found it following root to expand and when from this root no edges to expand, they will pick another root and keep on travel to unvisited node. 
right now i want to use this to extract spanning trees from graph. The number of trees is not only one. So right now i want to know when it start pick new root during traversal. 
so i can know which group of nodes belong to one spanning tree and other nodes belong to other trees.

Comment: i have a graph like 5->4->0->1->2 so right now i make it start from node 0 to traversal. it give me visited sequence like 0,1,2,4,5 but if i make it outcoming directions, it only give me 0,1,2. i want to randomly choose different root like 4 or 5 to finish all graph nodes, how to do this